# How to return back after Alt+Ctrl+Esc

Tags: shortcut-keys

Can anybody help me?
I did <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> in Ubuntu and deleted every thing in desktop and bottom.
How can I return back to my desktop?

Comment: Why did you tag this ubuntu-one?

Answer (score 5):

I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd> and it does not do anything.

My guess is that you did not hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd>, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (<kbd>ESC</kbd> and <kbd>F1</kbd> are just next to each other). That takes you to a command line interface. Just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to get back to your desktop environment.

By the way: you can access command line interfaces with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> + either of the following keys: <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F3</kbd>, <kbd>F4</kbd>, <kbd>F5</kbd>, <kbd>F6</kbd>.